# How to fix issues when remove LetsEncrypt certificate in single domain on centos 7 server

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl-certificate, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have installed lets-encrypt in centos 7 server

```
yum install epel-release
yum install certbot-nginx
```

and config nginx.conf with `server_name opvietnam.com www.opvietnam.com;` After that I reload nginx open firewall with port 443 and generate ssl

```
certbot --nginx -d opvietnam.com -d www.mywebsite.com
```

All OK but I config with options 2.Oneday, I want to remove its? 
I try the test domain. Installing step by step in the test domain
And search how to remove LetsEncrypt on single domain.
By the way, I see WTF tuts in [this website](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/comment/reply/2687#comment-form). I used the ways follow his tutorial

```
rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/[testdomainname]/
rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/[testdomainname]/
rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/[testdomainname].conf
```

[Panic]. When I installed ssl in another domain again. It displayed one error

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for [domainname]
tls-sni-01 challenge for [www.domainname]
Cleaning up challenges
Cannot find a VirtualHost matching domain www.domainname
```

So how to fixed this error and `certbot revoke -d [sitename]`.Is it the best way to remove a single Certbot (lets-encrypt) certificate on single domain?

Comment: Does the removed domain share a certificate with any other domain? That is, is the certificate a SAN entry with any other domain?

Comment: No. I used one certificate for one domain. peer to peer and not share with any other domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `www.domainname` is not the same domain of which certificate you just removed. The error `Cannot find a VirtualHost matching domain www.domainname` suggests the problem is not with Let's Encrypt, but with configuration tests the `certbot` performs.

Although you are using Nginx, the error message uses Apache terminology, `VirtualHost`. See `server { }` section in Nginx configuration whether it has [`server_name www.domainname;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) or not. You may also have combined `server_name domainname www.domainname;`. If you don't, add one.

Comment: Actually first I use Apache + nginx together. And now I migrated from apache + nginx to nginx + php-fpm. one domain on multidomain have configured with Let's Encrypt. I removed its with this tutorial. These website still active but when I want to add one ssl to new website. It displays issue `Cannot find a VirtualHost matching domain www.domainname.com`.Could you give me a the best link tutorial how to configure after migrating from apache + nginx to nginx + php-fpm

Comment: `server {
    listen      <ip>:80;
    server_name  domainname www.domainame;
    root        xxx;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  xxx combined;
`
That's server block what I configured